# IBM Notes query using formula language in java

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I am using the NCSO.jar API to query a NSF for info. I pass to the database.search method the following query:

```
 "isAdminSite := AdminSite = \"DSTMOP\":\"DSTFrance\";isITCS104 := 
ServerStateSecurity = \"G3\":\"G4\";isArchived := Archive = \"Internal
\":\"External\";isOnline := ServerStateNetwork = \"ON\"; isWindows := OS = 
\"Windows\"; SELECT Form = \"Server\" & isAdminSite & isITCS104 & 
!isArchived & isOnline & isWindows".
```

The problem is with the `isWindows` filter. If I have something like Windows 2008 or Windows Server R2 in the document, it won't fetch it.

Is there something like the `like` operator in SQL or `contains` in Java that I can use here? Any ideas on how I can modify this query?

Also, I would like to compare dates. Any ideas on how I can do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[@Contains()](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CONTAINS.html?lang=en)** to test if a string is part of another string.

```
... isWindows := @Contains(OS; \"Windows\"); ...
```

[Comparing Date/Time Values](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/05022009100728PMAGU5MB.htm):

> In formula language, date/times can be compared using the normal
>   comparison operators <, = and so on. A later date/time is considered
>   greater.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. For the date/time problem, i needed to fetch all the documents created in the last 7 days. I used @Created > @Adjust(@Now;0;0;-7;0;0;0)

Comment: You're welcome. Your formula gives you documents from current minute back seven days. If you want to get documents for whole days then use `@Date(@Created) > @Adjust(@Today;0;0;-7;0;0;0)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Matches("Windows*")`.

See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_MATCHES.html) for the details on the patterns that @Matches can work with.